# Formulating an algorithm for a group sorting program with exclusionfactors

Tags: algorithm, sorting, combinatorics

I'm trying to formulate an equation/algorithm to solve this problem (for a program I'm writing):

Rules:

- A person, p, that is to be sorted can exclude n amount of people from the list. The excluded people, n, cannot be in the same group as p.
- The list will contain around 100-150 people.
- A group should contain 5-7 people (ideally 6)

My current thoughts:

- Take the list count and divide it by 6, which will give me the amount of groups.
- Feed people into the groups untill an exclusion occurs. When this happens, try to move the mismatched persons into other groups, based on some sort of score-system untill proper groups are formed.

However, I still feel like I need to put a limit on the amount of people allowed to be excluded per person.

My question is basically how I would figure out how many people a certain person can exclude to make this endeavor possible. Considering there will be around 150 people, each with its own list of persons to exclude, is it even possible? However, some exceptions are ofcourse allowed. Ideas and thoughts are also appriciated!

I'm planning to write the program in java.

Comment: Bad cases: One person excluded by everybody. One person excluding all other persons. I'd count how many times each person is excluded, start building groups around them (and persons with long exclusion lists) first.

Comment: Thanks, that is indeed a great starting point! However, the first two scenarios can be (hopefully) avoided by limiting the amount of persons each person can exclude. I'm wondering how to figure out the biggest exclusion list count possible, while keeping the probability of clashes at a minimum.

Comment: Actually, @StefanHaustein's first scenario can't be avoided by limiting the number of people each person can exclude.

Comment: @j_random_hacker true, however, it's very unlikely that it'll happen in my case :)! (also, that's why i put hopefully in there)

Comment: You can apply [this idea](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35445655/47984) to this problem, with the variation that you make the final team possibly a smaller size.

Comment: @j_random_hacker Seems very promising, but I'm having a problem of figuring out how to assign people their slots, "Finally, connect up each person-vertex with all the slot-vertices that they are permitted to fill", I'd have to fill slots first to figure out where people should be excluded from, which kind of makes this solution a bit redundant perhaps? Also, it doesn't quite awnser how I should limit the exclusion list.

I might just be a bit slow. Thanks a lot for the input though :)!

Comment: @Remmie: You're right, that other problem isn't a perfect fit.  I'll write a quick answer in a second...

Comment: I don't have time to give a full answer, but in short you can profitably model this as the problem of finding an [equitable colouring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equitable_coloring) in a graph in which each person is a vertex and there is an edge between any two people whenever either one wants to exclude the other.  This will produce a set of groups such that (a) within each group, no person wants to exclude any other person, (b) each group is roughly equally sized, and (c) there are as few groups as possible.  (If they're too big, you can of course subdivide them arbitrarily.) ...

Comment: ...  Happily the Hajnal–Szemerédi theorem (see the linked page) guarantees that if the largest number of people excluded by any one person is d, then an equitable colouring with at most d+1 colours (groups) can be achieved, so that e.g. if there were 150 people and at most 9 exclusions per person, each group would be at least 150/(9+1) = 15 people (which as I said, you can then subdivide as you wish).  Also this can be found in polynomial time! :)

Comment: @j_random_hacker Thank you so much! You've been of tremendous help :)!

Comment: You're welcome, hope it's practically useful to you :)